# Installing numpy 1.3.0 64-bit for Python 2.6.2 64-bit

Tags: python, abaqus

I am having problem importing `numpy` module into **Python**. I have installed Python 2.6.2 (for 64-bit) and its corresponding `numpy` package (64-bit) from the following URL: [numpy-1.3.0.win-amd64-py2.6.msi](http://dfn.dl.sourceforge.net/project/numpy/NumPy/1.3.0/numpy-1.3.0.win-amd64-py2.6.msi)

I am getting the following error:
[image]

I need the version of numpy for 64-bit Python 2.6.2 as I need to use it as a module in ABAQUS 6.10 python environment.

Comment: Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Any reason why you use such an outdated version of numpy (at the moment of writing the latest version is 1.9) ? You should try with a more recent version.

Comment: Both ABAQUS 6.10 and 6.12 uses Python version 2.6.2. Thank you for your response, the problem has been resolved.